# How to use multithreading for faster execution, while calling functions recursively in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, recursion, concurrency, filesystems

I have below C++ code to copy files, folders, hard links, soft links etc. recursively to another directory, I want to call the functions via a multithreading approach for faster copying :
i.e. I want to call cpDirectory, cpFile, and cpSoftLink functions via thread concurrently or parallelly whichever is better.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;


//function to  copy files
void cpFile(const fs::path & srcPath,
  const fs::path & dstPath) {

  std::ifstream srcFile(srcPath, std::ios::binary);
  std::ofstream dstFile(dstPath, std::ios::binary);

  if (!srcFile || !dstFile) {
    std::cout << "Failed to get the file." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  
  dstFile << srcFile.rdbuf();

  srcFile.close();
  dstFile.close();
}

// function to copy soft links

void cpSoftLink(const fs::path & srcPath, const fs::path & dstpath){
// if symbolic link already exists then don't create it again
    if ( !fs::exists(dstpath) ) {
         fs::create_symlink(fs::read_symlink(srcPath),dstpath);
        }
}



//function create new directory and copy

void cpDirectory(const fs::path & srcPath,
  const fs::path & dstPath) {

  fs::create_directories(dstPath);

  for (const auto & entry: fs::directory_iterator(srcPath)) {
    const fs::path & srcFilePath = entry.path();
    const fs::path & dstFilePath = dstPath / srcFilePath.filename();
    //if the path is directory then create new folder
    if (fs::is_directory(srcFilePath)) {
      cpDirectory(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);
    }
    // if its a symbolic link, then read it and create new symbolic link in the new path to preserve it.
    else if (fs::is_symlink(srcFilePath)){
        std::filesystem::path p(srcFilePath);
            cpSoftLink(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);

    }


    //simply copy the regular files 
    else {

      if (fs::hard_link_count(srcFilePath) > 1){        
         std::cout<<srcFilePath;
      }
      cpFile(srcFilePath, dstFilePath);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  const auto root = fs::current_path();
  // Argument contains Source and Destination Path
  const fs::path srcPath = argv[1];
  const fs::path dstPath = argv[2];

  // Start the File Sync 
  cpDirectory(srcPath, dstPath);

  return 0;

}
```

Please help, As I am a beginner in C++.

Comment: First find full paths of all files, symlinks etc. and store them in a vector. Then create some threads and execute those functions based on the type of element in the vector. Maybe use a struct with source path, destination path and type as members.

Comment: To build on the suggestion by @kiner_shah, instead of having a struct with a type, have a base structure, with an abstract `copy` function. Then inherit from this abstract base structure, once for each type of "file", and implement the proper `copy` semantics. Store pointer to the base structure (initialized as pointers to the concrete structures) in the vector. Plain basic polymorphism in other words.

Comment: Sequential file handling is usually faster unless you have special hardware (multiple disks in a cluster). So why do you think multithreading will help here?

Comment: Multithreading is not a magic wand that will make everything faster, you need to understand the whole system to find what the bottleneck is and optimize that part. Accessing a single resource with multiple threads will even be slower because synchronization needs to happen and threads start to wait on each other.

Comment: sound like a job for rsync ....